# How to get value of a node with namespace prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

So, I have got the following query that I tried to get the value between the nodes:

```xml
<oas:Base64Assertion>235fkl53</oas:Base64Assertion>
```

I want to extract the value `235fkl53`. I tried with the following query:

```
declare @x xml = '
  <soapenv:Header>
    <oas:Security>
      <oas:Base64Assertion>
        <oas:Security xmlns:oas="http://example.com">
          <oas:Base64Assertion>235fkl53</oas:Base64Assertion>
        </oas:Security>
      </oas:Base64Assertion>
    </oas:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
';

select cast(@x.value('(//oas:Base64Assertion)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as xml).query('//value/text()') as cdata;
```

But I get the following error:

> Msg 2229, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 XQuery [value()]: The name "oas"
> does not denote a namespace.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have urls for xml namespace used in the document?

Comment: @SalmanA Sorry I did not understand your question. What is it that you are asking?

Comment: Your xml is rejected by sql server (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fceeda0de55c796214e6efbc68483283). are there any elements before the `<soapenv:Header>`?

Comment: @SalmanA Isn't the above XML valid? There are more elements but will that make any difference ?

Comment: Does it have `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">` at the beginning?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, it has that node also.

Comment: Side points: `//` descendant axis is slow, it's better to just put the whole path in. Looks like you actually have Base64, so you can change your data type to `varbinary` and it will decode it for you. And `max` probably isn't necessary unless you think it will be over 8kb long. Finally you don't need to use both `value` and `query`, you can just do `@x.value('(/soapenv:Header/oas:Security/oas:Base64Assertion/oas:Security/oas:Base64Assertion/text())[1]', 'varbinary(100)')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You did not add the namespaces in the XML you posted so I have added them in the following example based on where I think they should be.*

You need to add `WITH NAMESPACE` before using namespace prefixes in XQueries:

```
declare @x xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:oas="http://example.com">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <oas:Security>
      <oas:Base64Assertion>
        <oas:Security>
          <oas:Base64Assertion>235fkl53</oas:Base64Assertion>
        </oas:Security>
      </oas:Base64Assertion>
    </oas:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Envelope>
';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://example.com' AS oas)
SELECT @x.value('(//oas:Base64Assertion)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');

SELECT @x.value('declare namespace oas="http://example.com"; (//oas:Base64Assertion)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42689ffaf8ddca223e6f1b8a43e0d9a2)